# spring mvc how to store commonly-used collections

Tags: spring-mvc, architecture

This is an architecture question. I have Spring MVC web application that holds about a dozen collections that are rarely changed but that are often used in many-to-one relationships and for populating the drop-down selects that set the values of those properties. (For example: country, region, status types, etc).

In terms of performance and memory use, how should the app make these collections available?

At the moment I have a singleton wrapper class like the following:

```
@Component("collectionWrapper")
public class CollectionWrapper {
    Map<Integer, Country> countries;
    Map<Integer, User> users;
    Map<Integer, Office> offices;
    Map<Integer, Status> statuses
    DAOService daoService;

    public CollectionWrapper() {}

    @Autowired(required=true)
    public CollectionWrapper(DAOService daoService) {
        this.daoService=daoService;
        loadCountriesFromDao();
        loadUsersFromDao();
        loadOfficesFromDao();
        loadStatusesFromDao();
    }

    public void loadCountriesFromDao() {
        countries=daoService.getCountries();
    }

    // etc...
}
```

In the rare cases that an item in one of the collections is changed, the controller responsible for making the change calls `collectionWrapper.loadCountriesFromDao()`, for example.

Finally, the main objects that the app deals with have properties that map to these "reference objects", like so:

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Office office;

    etc...
}
```

So basically I'm wondering if this is the right way to be doing this. It is convenient to simply inject the collectionWrapper into my controllers and views, but I'm not sure how efficient it is on a lower level or if I'm missing something fundamental.

Thanks for sharing your experience!